# How to get next element in array

Tags: php, arrays

When I dump my array I revieve records. I'd like to stop forear if condition is met and move index to the next element but I dont understand something.
I use:

```
    foreach ($this->pages[0] as $key => $val){
        if ($key == 2){
            dump($val);
        }   
    }
```

after `dump($this->pages[0])` I recieve array

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Wstęp
            [symbol] => wstep
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Prezentacja spółki
            [symbol] => prezentacja-spolki
        )
)
```

`dump($val)` returns

```
Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Wstęp
        [symbol] => wstep
    )
```

an the problem is when I try move to next element in array using

```
dump(next($val));
```

returns

```
Prezentacja spółki
```

Hov to properly move to pointer to naxt element in array ?

Comment: next($key)? did you tried that

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to do but if you want the next value in the array you are currently looping through, I think you would need to call next on that array. So... `next($this->pages[0])`

Answer (score 1):

In a `foreach` loop you use `continue` to stop the current element process and advance to the next element

```
foreach ($this->pages[0] as $key => $val){
    if ($key == 2){
        continue; // Go to the next element
    }   
}
```

To stop the loop entirely, use `break` instead of `continue`

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what if i have more elements in array and need to stop foreach after moved poiner to next element ? dump($val) return me all enements in array exept $key == 2 ?

Comment: So you want to stop the loop entirely?

Comment: Yes, becouse I'd like to reach some next element in array depends on changing condition.

Comment: I resolved it by: `foreach ($this->pages[0] as $key => $val){
                if ($key == $_GET['page_id']){
                    $myCond = true;
                    continue;
                }   
                if ($myCond == true) {
                    dump(($val));
                    break;
                }
            }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the foreach loop to skip directly to the next element. you can use:

```
continue;
```